Why doesn't the future barry_as_FLUFL work in a .py file?
There is a future statement which enables using the diamond operator <> instead of != for equality comparisons.
Here is a demonstration in a REPL:
>>> from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL
>>> print(1 <> 2)
True
>>> 1 != 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 != 2
      ^^
SyntaxError: with Barry as BDFL, use '<>' instead of '!='

It also works as expected with eval, exec, and compile, e.g.:
>>> import __future__
>>> exec(compile('print(1 <> 2)', 'foo', 'single', __future__.CO_FUTURE_BARRY_AS_BDFL))
True

However, it doesn't work when used in a script.
# script.py
from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL
print(1 <> 2)

Whether you import or run the file, that syntax change doesn't take effect:
$ python3 script.py
  File ".../script.py", line 3
    print(1 <> 2)
            ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm aware that the feature is a joke, and its functionality may have only been checked in an interactive interpreter. Nevertheless, I'm interested in the technical reason why, unlike other future statements, it doesn't work in a .py file.
Why doesn't the future barry_as_FLUFL work in a script?

Yes, it only works in the REPL.  https://discuss.python.org/t/is-it-expected-that-the-barry-as-flufl-feature-doesnt-work-outside-of-repl/9128/2

@TimRoberts It does not only work in the REPL, it also works with compile, in all modes ("exec", "single", "eval") as mentioned in the question.

Related: gh-125331: Allow the parser to activate future imports on the fly (regression of barry_as_FLUFL in Python 3.13)
